# Custom admin menu for a selection of pages

Tags: pages, admin, admin-menu

I have a site with 30-35 pages. The customer only needs to edit 3 of them on a regular basis. So to make it simpler and easier for them in the backend, I would like to create a new admin menu item and place those 3 pages under it. How do I do that?

Been thinking on custom post types but don't want to make it more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:** You could assign the role of "editor" to the user, assign the user as author of the three pages and thereafter limit the user to editing only those three pages by following this outlined methodology:

http://www.godaisies.com/2010/08/23/how-to-make-editors-only-able-to-edit-their-own-page-in-wordpress/

This however does not fulfill your requirement of a dedicated custom admin page. It simply limits what the user can do.

**Approach 2:** Create a custom admin page as clearly outlined in the codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus) and fork the code used for listing pages in wp-admin.

**Approach 3:** Use Role Scoper, a free plugin that allows:

> additional Read or Edit access for specific Pages, Posts or Categories

...and...

> Specify element(s) in Edit Form to withhold from non-Editors

http://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/

Approach 2, 3 or a combination of 1, 2 or 3 ensures the key to your required functionality.

Comment: Thanks. The tricky part is the code for listing pages in admin and also just the specific pages.

Comment: @BoBoz What have you attempted thus far? At which juncture and with what line of code have you experienced "trickiness".